# Do these two sentences have the same meaning?

Tags: meaning

(1) Advertisers are not getting as much value for the money spent with violent content as with non-violent content.

(2) Advertisers are not getting as much value with violent content as with non-violent content for the money spent.

Comment: both sentence have the same meaning.

Comment: Both sentences are equally poorly worded and confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct but they are not clearly written. Perhaps you could try something like, "Advertisers are receiving more value with non-violent content than violent content."